# Верстка табиков на странице "Вопросы с меткой"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Ломается верстка панели вкладок на странице "Вопросы с меткой", когда есть конкурсные вопросы.

Если конкурсных вопросов нет, все влезает хорошо.

Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

[image: скрин]

Comment: Не могу подтвердить. На Chrome 41.0.2272.118 все в порядке.

Comment: Подтверждаю. @AlexanderIvanov не ту ссылку может быть смотрите? сейчас это можно увидеть например тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: @YuraIvanov, о! Понеслась. Подтверждаю =)

Comment: Вариантов, кроме как уменьшить длину какой-нибудь строки нет. Выхода три: 1) поменять "Вопросы с меткой", на "Вопросы", 2) поменять "Вопросы с меткой", на "По метке", 3) поменять название "часто упоминаемые" на что-то другое.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, "часто упоминаемые" -> "популярные" ? или "цитируемые"?

Comment: Сама формулировка "часто упоминаемых" очень хитрая. Пожалуйста, взгляните на нее. Цитируемые - очень близко, конечно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну это вопросы, на которые часто ссылаются, как я понял. Что наводит на размышления об индексе цитируемости -> "цитируемых".

Comment: @Nofate Сделал и то и другое. "часто упоминаемые" -> "цитируемые". "Вопросы по метке" -> "По метке".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, отлично. Не зря сегодня этот скриншот со стола удалил )